# Laravel: policy for viewAny always returns false

Tags: laravel

I looked at other similar questions but they are not helping.

My policy method `viewAny` for `User` always returns false even if the function body is literally just `return true`, so I'm not sure what's happening.

On my AuthServiceProvider, I have:

```
protected $policies = [
'App\Account' => 'App\Policies\AccountPolicy',
'App\User' => 'App\Policies\UserPolicy'
];
```

UserPolicy:

```
public function viewAny(User $user, Account $account) {
        // $role = $user->roles()->wherePivot('account_id', $account->id)->first();
        return true;
    }
```

UserController

```
protected $account;
    // just sharing this so you know where $account comes from

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function($req, $next){
            $this->account = Account::find($req->session()->get('account_id'));
            return $next($req);
        });
    }


public function index()
    {

        $this->authorize('viewAny', $this->account);

        $users = $this->account->users;

        $usersWithRoles = [];

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $usersWithRoles['user'] = $user;
            $usersWithRoles['user']['role'] = $this->account->roles()->wherePivot('user_id', $user->id)->first();
        }


        return view('users.index', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
```

One thing to note is that my `User` routes are inside a grouping. So the actual uri looks like `/account/users`

```
Route::prefix('account')->group(function() {
   /**
   * Users
   */
   Route::resource('users', 'UserController')->only([
      'index', 'destroy', 'update', 'edit'
   ]);
});
```

The `index` route always returns false and a `403` page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
$this->authorize('viewAny', $this->account);
```

will make laravel look for a `viewAny` function in the `AccountPolicy`, not in the `UserPolicy`.

Basically you ask: can user view any account? 
Therefore it's an Account policy.

For an admin you might need: can user view any user? 
Than its a User policy.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, because if I remove the `Account $account` parameter from my `viewAny` method, it still doesn't work.

Comment: That's not my point. You are defining the `viewAny` function in the `UserPolicy` file, while it should be in the `AccountPolicy` file. Create a function in that file, and perform a `dump` call to actually pinpoint the fact that the function is called.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Before responding I made the `viewAny` method on the `AccountPolicy`, but didn't include the `Account $account` param and it didn't work. Just included it, and the `dump` happens. If I were to edit this question, would you help me adjust this so I can use the `UserPolicy` while including an `Account` instance?

Comment: Not really I think. This is just the way Laravel is utilizing these policies. You can of course redefine where laravel needs to look for the policies in the AuthServiceProvider, but to be honest, it's better to get yourself acquainted with how these policies work. They are very powerful. What would be incorrect in defining the `viewAny` in the `AccountPolicy`?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to create a policy on whether or not the authenticated user can view the list of users on an account. So basically if they can visit `/account/users`. I have policies for whether they can edit a certain user as well. for example, admins cannot edit other admins. The account is used because users can belong to different accounts with different roles

Comment: And to answer your question about why it would be incorrect: Wouldn't I have to put every single method for all resources (reports, users, campaigns, etc) on this one policy?

Comment: So it is: "view-users" on `$account`: `$this->authorize('view-users', $account);` For this you need to define a `viewUsers` function in the `AccountPolicy`. And it is: "edit" on `$user`: `$this->authorize('edit', $user)` (in which you also check admin rights). Regarding your second comment: personally I create a Policy per model. It really depends on the model architecture I guess. In general, if you need to allow access on 'something' than define that in the policy of 'something'. Don't forget you can also refer to other policy checks inside you policies. E.g:  `$user->can('view', $account)`

Comment: Thanks, Maarten. I'm going to "un-edit" my question and give you best, since you set me in right direction. I did end up needing what you said - edit on UserPolicy. Still fuzzy on how laravel auto-maps policy, but it will become clear. Thanks again!